# Callbacks/Promises in Firebase

Tags: firebase, angular

I trying to figure out why i am getting objects in //1 and //2 but getting undefined at //3...

I am messing around Angular2 with Typescript and Firebase back end.

What am i doing wrong here, seems to me like a rookie mistake...

```
    getPlayers() {
        var snap;
        this.playersRef.once('value', function (snapshot) {
                snap = snapshot.val();
//1
                console.info("snap.val()" + snapshot.val());
//2
                console.info("var snap" + snap);

            }
        );
//3
        console.info("var snap loc 2" + snap);
        //return new Promise<Player[]>(resolve => resolve(snap));
    }
```

///////// EDIT /////////////////////////////////////////////

Can someone explain how this pertains to the Firebase nosql DB in particular (Inside of Angualr2 app).

in my app.component.ts file i have this

```
    constructor(private _playerService: PlayerService){}

    getPlayers(){
        this._playerService.getPlayers().then(res => this.players = res);
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getPlayers();
    }
```

inside the player.service.ts file I have this

```
getPlayers() {
    this.playersRef.once('value', function (snap){
        return snap.val();
    });
}
```

I always get TypeError: this._playerService.getPlayers(...) is undefined

I've read some atricle such as this
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html

but i still can't figure out how to make everything work together.

Also when i try to edit my `getPlayer()` with promises (insead of callbacks) like in the article i get an exception stating that `.once()` needs at least two parameters so I'm not sure how the article is working at all with `.once('value').then()`

Comment: yes, async with Firebase

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `this.playersRef.once` is asynchronous.

This means that the third `console` statement will run prior to the callback of `once` executing, thus the `snap` variable will still be `undefined` at that point in time.

So, the sequence of `console` statements is actually 3, 1, 2, rather than 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined since //3 is executed immediately, even though the callback may not necessarily have run by the time the //3 log statement is called, meaning `snap` won't have been set yet. It's not `undefined` because of scoping issues, it's `undefined` because it's not set at the time you check the value.

Running this, you should realize that //3 immediately gives you undefined, **then** //1 prints, **then** //2 prints. Think about that.

Comment: yup, i saw that in the console.  Makes sense.